# Defining lambda value for ridge regression

Tags: r, ridge-regression

I try to understand ridge regression. I think the most important point in it is defining lambda value. I researched some R codes but I didn't understand how to define it. In the example [here](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~cao/Teaching/852/Ridge.R), in the section copied below:

```
# Selection of constant is at endpoint.  Extend endpoint and try again
 ridgec <- lm.ridge (y ~ x1+x2+x3c, lambda = seq(0, 1, .1))
 plot(ridgec)
 select(ridgec)

# Selection of constant is at endpoint.  Extend endpoint and try again
 ridgec <- lm.ridge (y ~ x1+x2+x3c, lambda = seq(0, 10, .01))
 plot(ridgec)
 select(ridgec)

# Final model uses lambda=4.
 ridge.final <- lm.ridge (y ~ x1+x2+x3c, lambda = 4)
```

How did he decide to use lambda value as 4?

Comment: Note that this isn't really about R.

Comment: I know it isnt about R.I try to understand the logic of defining lambda value in ridge regression

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is done using **cross validation**.  I wont go into that here, as there are extensive resources on this site about how to tune $\lambda$ in ridge regression using cross validation.

In your example, this does not seem to be the case, the `select` function is doing the work.  Here's the source for `select` as applied to ridge regression objects

```
> getAnywhere(select.ridgelm)
A single object matching ‘select.ridgelm’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for select from namespace MASS
  namespace:MASS
with value

function (obj) 
{
    cat("modified HKB estimator is", format(obj$kHKB), "\n")
        cat("modified L-W estimator is", format(obj$kLW), "\n")
    GCV <- obj$GCV
        if (length(GCV)) {
            k <- seq_along(GCV)[GCV == min(GCV)]
            cat("smallest value of GCV  at", format(obj$lambda[k]), 
            "\n")
    }
}
```

Looks like the `select` function is using a statistic called `GCV` to select $\lambda$, by finding the value that minimizes `GCV`.  I believe this is **generalized cross validation**.  I am not an expert in this area (I tend to just use straight cross validation, and I would recommend you do the same), but if you are very interested, [here is a paper](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wahba/ftp1/oldie/golub.heath.wahba.pdf) that seems to have all the details:

Comment: As a tangential comment, I would also recommend using the `glmnet` library over `lm.ridge`.  It is fast, modern, and has many wonderful features.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.The page is so complex,i will try to understand it